# How can I filter off thumbnails attachments in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I wrote a BeautifulSoup script scraping pictures of a forum in earlier days, and it's working fine from the second page and on. The first page has few posts have attachment some thumbnails which are jpeg files, but it's not a valid link to download.

I didn't try much on the codes, so I just scrape from page 2 and on. But I still wanna scrape from the very first page.

```
import requests
import bs4
import re

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
                  'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/73.0.3683.105 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/2.4.1488.38'
}
url = "http://www.sechongse.com/forum/thread-10106367-1-1.html"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
soup_imgs = soup.find(name='div', attrs={'class':'t_msgfont'})\
        .find_all('img', alt="", src=re.compile(".jpg"))
for i, img in enumerate(soup_imgs, 1):
    src = img['src']
    print(src)
```

DOM

```
attachments/month_1809/20180920_97a05cfc4ae8f0950356vcm54UmZbB5C.jpg
attachments/month_1809/20180920_c9f7ee5420e277ade049cdwQ7n5sQ3Nj.jpg
attachments/month_1809/20180920_111cbfcd81acbe556bceI8ZZluQ7mwvY.jpg
attachments/month_1809/20180920_e94dafd7c8b1ca99c1035YS0TnpdUCHO.jpg

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Posts like this are pretty easy to find in my script, and yet, I can't get away with these attachments, so how can I get around with it then? Any methods? re?

Comment: something more like: yes i want .jpeg files, but not attachments....jpeg. ||| or i want those jpeg starting with http(s) which i can download to my HDD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done with Beautiful Soup 4.7+.

Seems like CSS selectors may work out well for you in this one. Here we check that the src ends with `.jpg`, but does not start with `attachments`. We can use `$=` to test the end of an attribute and `^=` to test the start:

```
import bs4

html = """
<img src="attachments/month_1809/20180920_97a05cfc4ae8f0950356vcm54UmZbB5C.jpg"/>
<img src="some/other/image/20180920_97a05cfc4ae8f0950356vcm54UmZbB5C.jpg"/>
"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for img in soup.select('img[src$=".jpg"]:not([src^=attachments])'):
    src = img['src']
    print(src)
```

Output

```
some/other/image/20180920_97a05cfc4ae8f0950356vcm54UmZbB5C.jpg
```

---

For those who don't like using selectors

```
import bs4
import re

html = """
<img src="attachments/month_1809/20180920_97a05cfc4ae8f0950356vcm54UmZbB5C.jpg"/>
<img src="some/other/image/20180920_97a05cfc4ae8f0950356vcm54UmZbB5C.jpg"/>
"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for img in soup.find_all('img', src=re.compile('^(?!attachments).*\.jpg$')):
    src = img['src']
    print(src)
```

Comment: i found this one from a friend, which matches as well.
`src=re.compile("(http.*?jpg)", re.S)`

Comment: I will write your help also in my script for studying purposes, thx chief!

Comment: Yeah, there are often multiple ways to get things done, glad you got it working.